# third party SAML integration with WSO2 UES

Tags: java, wso2, saml-2.0

I need to integrate a third party SAML provider to WSO2 UES. The developed application works fine when deployed in tomcat, but on deploying the same in UES, the response is not coming back to the consumerurl.

Please assist.

Comment: Do your requirement is to integrate third party SSO provider? What's the provider that you trying to incorporate?

Comment: yes, I have a third party SSO provider, which I need to integrate to my UES.

Comment: What is the external SSO provider? Shibboleth?